# Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 doesn't detect hard drive during installation from USB

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server 20.04.6 on an HP Envy Desktop TE02-XXXX that runs the BIOS in UEFI mode, has two M.2 SSD hard drives and Windows 10 preinstalled. I created the bootable USB with Refus (4.1) using GPT partition scheme. When I get to the point of memory configuration in the installer, it only detects the USB itself but not the hard drive of the machine. If I create a bootable USB with same procedure for Ubuntu server 22.04.2, the hard drive gets detected. The problem must therefore be with the version 20.04.6 iso (perhaps missing or not appropriate drives) and unfortunately I strictly need 20.04.
I do not have any of the options mentioned in similar posts to configure the UEFI BIOS except disabling the secure boot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 media if using the GA kernel stack (*default for Server media, but selected by the media you download*) is two years older than your 22.04 LTS media (*more if you selected 22.04.2 media using a HWE kernel stack*), where the kernel impacts kernel modules of course (*those commonly called drivers*).  You can also influence how the media detects your hardware by the options used during write with some software (inc. `rufus`).

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, could you please elaborate more on Rufus options to improve the hardware detection of the media? I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? And if system newer than 20.04, you may need 22.04 to have latest kernel & drivers to support newer hardware.

Comment: Its not that you can make Rufus detect more, Rufus has reformat options that **reduce** the hardware the machine will boot & install to, thus my suggestion was to not use any reformat options offered by rufus.  ie. full hardware is available if the ISO is *cloned* to media & booted without format changes; but yes some hardware will boot faster if reformatted (but that format change also prevents other machines from booting!) you can can write ISO so it'll only boot on uEFI hardware (not BIOS) or vise-versa.. Simple clone works on all (*even if slower on some*). Don't forget 20.04 is 2020-April

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I have MSI katana B 13 I have faced two problems (graphics problem cant change resolution from the safe boot resolution settings and able to access storage devices) both due to ubuntu didnt install the required drivers in the base image. The only available option is to install the image on an older device and clone the system to the target device. We can also open issue in ubuntu since they still support ubuntu 20.04